# Passing GUID parameter into a SQL function which accepts Guid parameter in c#

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net

I have used session to get the value from the previous page. i.e `UserId` and then trying to pass this value to the `GetDataByUserId(@guidparam)` function of SQL. And then to pass this retrieved value to the grid view as mentioned below.

Error:

> Failed to enable constraints. One or more rows contain values violating non-null, unique, or foreign-key constraints.

Please help me out of this problem.

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!this.IsPostBack)
    {
        DSRolesTableAdapters.aspnet_RoleUsersTableAdapter userRoleAdapter = new DSRolesTableAdapters.aspnet_RoleUsersTableAdapter();

        DataTable dt = new DataTable();

        Guid user = Guid.NewGuid();
        user = Guid.Parse(Session["UserId"] as string);

        dt = userRoleAdapter.GetDataByUserId(user);//Error at this line

        UserRolesGrdView.DataSource = dt;
        UserRolesGrdView.DataBind(); 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This was a little long for a commnet.

problem is with the `Datatable` you are returning by `userRoleAdapter.GetDataByUserId`, you have defined some `unique` or `not null` constraints on it which are not compatable with the data you are retrieving from the database, I mean when filling the `datatable` some of the data violates with these constraints and program gives error. remove the none required not null and unique constraints on the DataTable (set `allow null=true` and `is unique=false`), it will fixed.

*Notice:* Also The `number of fields`, `length` and the `datatype` of the fields of the datatable should be compatible with data you are trying to fill the datatable with.

Comment: i tried by setting (allow DB null= true and unique = false) but the same error comes out @Farheg

Comment: @RagwanKushawaha, you check the datatype, length and number of fields in your DataTable, the data you are retrieving from database should be compatible with the structure of your datatable.

Comment: there is -1 value assigned to maximum length field of **UserId**. Is it the right way? I am new to this asp.net and c#. please help me @Farheg

Comment: what is the type of UserId?, you may be able to change it to String with maximum length of 64 or higher

Comment: No, it is not allowed to change the type. it is currently _Sytem.Guide_ type @Farheg

Comment: I'm really sorry, please accept my apologize, as I don't know exactly what and how are the codes and scenario, so I can't say anything more. I hope you'll get it fixed soon. good lick.